# Angular ng-src when changing source of an image not updating scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the snippet below inside of my controller:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    for(var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
        var file = $files[i];

        $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
            url: '/smart2/api/files/profile',
            file: file
        }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.photo = data;
        });
    }
}
```

When the user loads the page, they can click a modal to upload a profile photo.  In that modal it has their current profile photo shown and an upload input.

I have `ng-src` attached to the image tag which is all working fine.  However, when the user uploads a new profile photo, in the `success` function for the upload call I set `$scope.photo` (which is referenced in `ng-src`).

I know that I need to inform Angular that it has changed but don't know how.  The returned data from the HTTP call will always be the same data already in `ng-src` or `$scope.photo` but it will change.

The name of the profile photo is the user's name, so even when they upload a new photo the file name or source remains the same, but the actual file is different.

Problem is, the photo is not updating when I set the `$scope.photo` in the success function.  What could the problem be?

Comment: is the function inside`$scope.apply` called?

Comment: It's not a function I'm just setting `$scope.photo` equal to the response from the HTTP call.

Comment: the parameter to `$scope.apply` is a function. Is this function being called? Did you check?

Comment: I updated, how can I have it refresh the ng-src?

Comment: Do you mean that the contents that `src` points to changes but the URL stays the same and you want to force it to reread the URL?

Comment: I added some more to the OP.  File name/location stays the same but the image changes when they upload.  That's why I need a "refresh" effect.

Comment: add a tmestamp to the URL and update the timestamp to make it change the URL.

Comment: Put it in an answer so I can accept/upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that the contents that `src` points to changes but the URL stays the same and you want to force it to reread the URL? If so, then you can add a tmestamp to the URL and update the timestamp to make it change the URL.

You also can set your `src` to the base64 encoded string with the image instead of a URL.

Comment: What if I have the image in another place (that I want to update), but it is inside of a different controller?  What are my options there?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. It sounds like you might need to use a service in all these controllers.

Comment: It's updated in the modal, and I want it to update everywhere else on the page.

Comment: make a service. a service is a singleton object. inject the service into everything that is interested in it. put the image source into the service. make this service maintain the image. expose the image from the service and make whatever is interested in this image watch it. Does this make sense?

Comment: I understand, but then it sends multiple HTTP requests for the same data.

Comment: Well, what it sends depends on the implementation... It should not send requests for the same data.

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem, I got an answer for the other problem in another question and the solution was to use $scope.$emit and $scope.$on

Comment: yes, no problem. I find events more difficult to maintain. I would make a service.

Comment: I have a service for it when the page loads as well as an event so that it can update when the user uploads.